# Can I develop ubuntu apps in Gambas

Tags: development, gtk, application-development, application-submission

As this [new platform](http://developer.ubuntu.com/) is released where developers can publish there apps, I would like to know if [Gambas](http://gambas.sourceforge.net/en/main.html) applications are good enough to submit.

Gambas is in my opinion the easiest way to develop applications for Linux with a very flat learning curve. Why use only "Quickly"? I think Gambas should also be mentioned on the website.

Are there ways can I submit an application created in Gambas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applications can be written in whatever language/framework you want to write them in, they just need to follow the [publishing requirements](http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/):

> - Be in one, self-contained directory
> - Be able to be installed into /opt/
> - Be able to be executed by all users from /opt/
> - Note: Users only have read and not write privileges to this
>     directory.
> - Write all configuration settings to ~/. (This can be one
>     file or a directory containing multiple configuration files.)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to develop gambas applications in Ubuntu, yes. I don't agree at all that it is the easiest way to learn, however. Ubuntu supports all programming languages you've heard of, and a lot of languages you've never heard of. But programming with Python, GTK and Quickly is insanely much easier, faster and more fun than programming from scratch with Gambas.

Comment: Thanks both of you for replies. I wish I could choose both answers as acceptable. But I have to choose one and jorge's properly formated answer deserves to become acceptable.
By the way quickly is greate tool but gambas user interface and packaging system is totally GUI based. And Basic language is easier. Python for sure is more versetile. It is just about matter of choice.

Comment: With Quickly, you'll just draw your user interface. Almost everything is GUI, if you want it to be. Also, with GTK 3.2,your GTK application will also run as a HTML5 application if you want it to, without any extra coding. And I know both Gambas and Python. I don't think Gambas is any easier. Quite the contrary. With Gambas, you have to consider data types, like Integers and simiar, whereas Python figures that out automatically.